# Nautical term used to the small objects of a sail that are passed though the mast ~ Translation of ‘garrucho’

Tags: single-word-requests, nautical-terms

I'm looking for a translation of this nautical term (taken from Spanish):

> **garrucho** 
> Objeto cilíndrico ubicado en el grátil de la vela mayor que, al ser pasado por la ranura del mástil, permite que ésta sea izada.

> **???**  
> A cylindric-shaped object situated on the luff of the mainsail which, when it's inserted through the mast's groove, allows it to be hoisted.

It's the number 2 (two) on this image taken from [Wikipedia article](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vela_(n%C3%A1utica)).

[image]

I couldn't find any site where it's mentioned. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was already familiar with the term "slide" for an analogous fitting. I think you're looking for ["slug"](https://www.yachtsandyachting.com/news/236327/Sail-Slides-and-Slugs-How-to-choose-correctly), which is described in the link as:

> a round or semicircle shape that is inserted into the track

Comment: Thanks! Was exactly what I was looking for